How many Consciousnesses could exist in a Matrioshka brain built around an O class star
(Note I am both autistic and new to this platform, I might not word or ask questions well and I might make questions confusing so if I do something wrong please tell me how to fix it)
So a civilization I am developing (basic information about the setting: I Wouldnt classify it as hard sci fi because it does have ftl travel and communication but other than that im trying to make it as hard sf as possible) So lets say some interstellar civilization builds a matrioshka brain around an O class star to replace their governors
How many CSC (city sized computers, using tokyo metropolitan as reference), PSC (planet sized computers, 2 variants, RPSC (rocky planet sized computers, using mars as reference) and GGSC (gas giant sized computers, using jupiter as reference) could potentially be in orbit of this O class star?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Within reason there is no practical limit to the number of objects that can be put into orbit around a given star.  However, without knowing what resources are available in the theoretical solar system and how much of those resources are required for each type of computer we can't even provide an answer.  (Obviously, if a RPSC uses 1/500th the resources of a GGSC then there are a vast number of possible combinations of the 3 types.)

well the civilization that made these things can mine entire planets, so lets say all resources in the O class systems kuiper belt whatever its called for extrasolar star systems

and if you ever wonder why they need multiple CSC/PSC, its because if the matrioshka had one consciousness, it could possibly be hacked, however, if there are multiple plural term for consciousness, the hacked individual could be patched or something

what im trying to say is, having one consciousness at that scale is just impractical, kinda like the stereotypical depiction of a dyson sphere being a shell fully enclosing the star

Please add all relevant information to the question itself (you can [edit] it).

As many as you want
Any star system is mostly empty space, meaning that you can fit a lot of stuff in orbit. Normally, there are limits as to what would be stable long-term due to interactions between bodies, but this isn't a problem with artificial orbits and station-keeping engines to correct orbits. You could easily turn the entire mass of the system, and probably all of its neighbors, into those massive computers around a star of your choosing, and still have spare room. Really the limit wouldn't be space, but shipping the mass across light years of space to get it to where you want to set up. Space is not a limiting factor here.
